# Como criar uma sequência de variáveis dummy com loop no r

Tags: r

Eu gostaria de criar *dummies* que identificassem a empresa na base de dados. Por exemplo, uma nova variável chamada "GLO"que valeria 1 se a variável empresa assumisse o valor GLO e 0 c.c.

A estrutura dos dados é assim:

```
head(tarifas)


    ano mes empresa origem destino tarifa assentos
1 2002   1     GLO   SBPA    SBBR 397,00       51
2 2002   1     GLO   SBSV    SBRF 272,00        5
3 2002   1     GLO   SBFL    SBGL 223,00      196
4 2002   1     GLO   SBGL    SBSP  96,00      615
5 2002   1     GLO   SBGL    SBRF 340,00      297
6 2002   1     GLO   SBSP    SBFL 145,00      189
```

O que tentei fazer foi usar o pacote dplyr junto com o for loop, mas algo está errado.
  Por exemplo, para criar um identificador para a empresa GLO e AZU, usei o seguinte código:

```
for (k in c("GLO", "AZU")) {
 tarifas2<- tarifas %>%
  mutate(paste0(k) = 0) %>%
  mutate(replace(paste0(k), empresa == paste0(",k,"),1))
}
```

Comment: Tente `model.matrix(~ 0 + empresa, df1)`. Mas note que é quase certo não ser preciso criar dummies explicitamente, as funções de modelação do R fazem isso automaticamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução R base, utilizando o exemplo da resposta do [Marcus Nunes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/411010/82237), mas com `set.seed` e com o nome do dataframe mudado.

```
set.seed(1234)
df1 <- data.frame(
  empresas = sample(c("GLO", "AZU"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)


model.matrix(~ 0 + empresas, df1)
#  empresasAZU empresasGLO
#1           1           0
#2           1           0
#3           1           0
#4           1           0
#5           0           1
#6           1           0
#7           0           1
#8           0           1
#9           0           1
#10          1           0
#attr(,"assign")
#[1] 1 1
#attr(,"contrasts")
#attr(,"contrasts")$empresas
#[1] "contr.treatment"
```

Ou, com este resultado no df original,

```
cbind(df1, model.matrix(~ 0 + empresas, df1))
#  empresas empresasAZU empresasGLO
#1      AZU           1           0
#2      AZU           1           0
#3      AZU           1           0
#4      AZU           1           0
#5      GLO           0           1
#6      AZU           1           0
#7      GLO           0           1
#8      GLO           0           1
#9      GLO           0           1
#10     AZU           1           0
```

Answer (score 1):

O pacote `onehot` faz isso automaticamente:

```
library(onehot)
empresas <- data.frame(
  empresas = sample(c("GLO", "AZU"), 10, replace = TRUE)
  )

empresas
##    empresas
## 1       AZU
## 2       AZU
## 3       GLO
## 4       GLO
## 5       AZU
## 6       AZU
## 7       GLO
## 8       AZU
## 9       AZU
## 10      AZU

dummy <- predict(onehot(empresas), empresas)
dummy
##       empresas=AZU empresas=GLO
##  [1,]            1            0
##  [2,]            1            0
##  [3,]            0            1
##  [4,]            0            1
##  [5,]            1            0
##  [6,]            1            0
##  [7,]            0            1
##  [8,]            1            0
##  [9,]            1            0
## [10,]            1            0
```

Se não for interessante que as colunas fiquem com nomes como `empresas=XXX`, basta usar a função `str_replace` do pacote `stringr` para substituir a string `empresas=` por nada nos nomes das colunas:

```
library(stringr)
colnames(dummy) <- str_replace(colnames(dummy),
                               "empresas=",
                               "")
dummy
##       AZU GLO
##  [1,]   1   0
##  [2,]   1   0
##  [3,]   0   1
##  [4,]   0   1
##  [5,]   1   0
##  [6,]   1   0
##  [7,]   0   1
##  [8,]   1   0
##  [9,]   1   0
## [10,]   1   0
```